# Probability of getting sum on 3 dice rolls

Tags: combinatorics

> The integers $1$ through $6$ appear on the six faces of a cube, one on each face. If three such cubes are rolled, what is the possibility that the sum of these numbers on the top faces is $17$ or $18$?

I understand the possibilities for $17$ which are $5+6+6\ldots$
I don't understand the possibilities to get $18$ as the sum. I know the method is $6\times 3$ but shouldn't there be $3$ possible ways to get $6+6+6$?

Shouldn't the problem be solved as $3(1/6^3)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of discussion, suppose that the dice are of three different colours, red, yellow and blue.

One way to get $6+6+6$ is red $6$, yellow $6$, blue $6$.

Another way is. . . ?

**PS**.  The answer should in fact be $4/6^3$.

Comment: you're saying that because "red, yellow, blue" and "red, yellow, blue" are the same thing there wouldn't be another way? Doesn't the 216 total possibilities for the possible numbers on the dice include repeats?

Comment: @Ben.  No, it treats the dice as being distinct.  $6^3$ counts: the 6 ways to role the red die, times the 6 ways to roll the yellow die, and times the 6 ways to roll the blue die.

Comment: @Graham thanks for supplying the reply to Ben while I was off-site ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of cases:

There are $6^3 = 216$ cases in total

Ways to get 17:

$$(5, 6, 6)$$
$$(6, 5, 6)$$
$$(6, 6, 5)$$

So there are $3$ ways.

Ways to get 18:

$$(6, 6, 6)$$

So there is only $1$ way.

Total # of ways: $3 + 1 = 4$ ways.

So probability is: $\large \frac{4}{216} = \frac{1}{54}$